# Create 200 news rows in table. Add average salary of original rows to the news rows?

Tags: plsql

I have been tasked with the following:
Write a PL/SQL anonymous block that inserts 100 employee IDs,
 starting at number 3000. Use a FOR loop (similar to the 100 you added starting at 2000).
 Add the AVERAGE salary of the *original* employees table (use SELECT!)
 in the salary column of the newly created employee rows.

So, I have created the new rows. These have employee ID's from 2000 - 3000.

I have to find the average of the all the rows that have employee ID below 2000 (the original rows in the table) and add this to the salary column of the new rows?

Can anyone give me some help with this?

Would it be something along the lines of

```
    UPDATE emp2 -- table name
        SELECT AVG( salary )
        FROM emp2
        WHERE employee_ID < 2000
```

Not too sure how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the below query,

```
UPDATE emp2
SET salary = (SELECT AVG(salary)
              FROM emp2
              WHERE employee_ID < 2000
              )
WHERE employee_id >= 2000;
```

Comment: Ahhh. That is great. Simpler than I thought!! Thank you so much!